# iPhone Metal API takes too long time (more than several seconds)

Tags: iphone, swift, metal

I tried to draw simple graph using Metal API. 
I've done similar job using OpenGL in Android and it takes 0.2~3 in old machine. But using Metal API, it takes more than 2~3 seconds in iPhone6s.

I call `render()` after `assignVertices(...)` in every 1 second.
And vertexData has more than 25000 vertices.
(For your reference 5000 vertices works well in 0.2 seconds).

How can I speed up following code?

Thanks!

```
var commandBuffer : MTLCommandBuffer!
var renderEncoder : MTLRenderCommandEncoder!

func assignVertices(vertices: Array<Vertex>, device: MTLDevice) {
    var vertexData = Array<Float>()
    for vertex in vertices{
        vertexData += vertex.floatBuffer()
    }

    // 2
    let dataSize = vertexData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertexData[0])
    vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize, options: [])!

    // 3
    vertexCount = vertices.count
}



func render(commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue, pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState, drawable: CAMetalDrawable, parentModelViewMatrix: Matrix4, projectionMatrix: Matrix4, clearColor: MTLClearColor?) {

    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .store

    renderEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!


    renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
    let nodeModelMatrix = self.modelMatrix()
    nodeModelMatrix.multiplyLeft(parentModelViewMatrix)
    let uniformBuffer = device.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements() * 2, options: [])
    let bufferPointer = uniformBuffer!.contents()
    memcpy(bufferPointer, nodeModelMatrix.raw(), MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements())

    renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(uniformBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
    memcpy(bufferPointer + MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements(), projectionMatrix.raw(), MemoryLayout<Float>.size * Matrix4.numberOfElements())
    renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertexCount, instanceCount: vertexCount / 3)

    renderEncoder.endEncoding()

    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Comment: I would not call makeBuffer() inside the render function if I were you. Also, are the memcpy() operations for large buffers? That could be the source of the slowdown.

Comment: Haven't really looked at your code in detail but I noticed you used `instanceCount: vertexCount / 3`. People new to Metal usually set the instance count wrong. Try using just `instanceCount: 1`.

Comment: Thank you  Matthijs, and MoDJ for your advice.  
InstanceCount makes this code be slower than GL code.  
I copied several lines from other examples and that's why I made this kinds of a mistake.   
Also I'll try to remove makeBuffer and memcopy from rendering routine as MoDJ's comments.